# Sandboxed Mac OS App, saving files in a shared location?

Tags: xcode, macos, sandbox, beta, macos-sierra

Have a Sandboxed Mac App. It downloads files to a location, and I want other files to be able to edit and overwrite the files.

Currently, I'm saving to the Documents Container via my App:

```
let path = manager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first!
```

I then am modifying via Preview and saving the file.

In OSX 10.11 El Capitan, this is fine. However, on Mac OS 10.12 Sierra Beta when the User attempts to save, we get the warning: "The original document can't be changed, so a duplicate with your changes has been created."

The same problem occurs when saving to Application Support.

Of course, this does make sense in that many use cases for Sandboxed Apps is that they won't want other Apps touching their content. Though is there a shared space in which Sandboxed Apps can allow other Apps modify their contents?